# addEventListener to array of HTMLDivElement

Tags: html, angular, typescript

For some reason the line: console.log(i + "What button did we click on");
Only ever produces '3What button...' i think it might have to do with my fat arrow function but i'm not sure a solution would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
 private SetUpHotSpots() {
    console.log("Entered SetupHotSpots");
    for (var i = 0; i < this.HotSpotArray.length; i++){
        console.log("Entered Loop: " + i);
        this.HotSpotArray[i].addEventListener("click", (() => {
            console.log(i + "What button did we click on");
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `let` instead of `var`. `for (let i = 0; i < this.HotSpotArray.length; i++){`

Comment: That resolved the issue thank you for your quick response if you make that into an answer ill give it an up vote and set it as a solution. @kavindra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `let` instead of `var`. `let` allows you to create variables that are limited to the block scope. So change your for loop like follows.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.HotSpotArray.length; i++){
```